# Gitlab pipeline - deploy subfolders to gitlab pages

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci-runner, storybook

I have a small [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) project that is hosted on Gitlab. I use Gitlab pages to host the storybook. The project builds at folder called `storybook-static` and then the files from this folder are served through gitlab pages.

I'm trying to make the pipeline so I can have three subfolders: `latest,` next`and`test` as follows:

1. When tag is created, the build files are moved to `public/latest`
2. When MR is merged, the build files are moved to `public/next`
3. When manually triggered, the build files are moved to `public/test`.

The three subdirectories co-exists, so updating `public/latest` does not affect `public/test`

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image: node:16-alpine

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm ci --legacy-peer-deps

build-and-deploy-latest:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build:storybook -c .storybook
    - rm -rf public/latest
    - mkdir -p public/latest
    - cp -r storybook-static/* public/latest
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

build-and-deploy-next:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build:storybook -c .storybook
    - rm -rf public/next
    - mkdir -p public/next
    - cp -r storybook-static/* public/next
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE == "merge"'

build-and-deploy-test:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build:storybook -c .storybook
    - rm -rf public/test
    - mkdir -p public/test
    - cp -r storybook-static/* public/test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  when: manual
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

The pipelines are triggered on the right events. I can see from the logs that the build is successful. When I browse the artifacts, I can see the files ( ex. `public/latest/index.html` ) exists.  When I download the folder with the artifacts and spin static server locally, it serves the index.html.

But opening the gitlab pages `/next` , `/latest` or `/test` gives me 404. I waited a day ( in case if it was cache, or runner needed time, etc ) and I still see 404s.

Answer (score 1):

You can only publish one and exactly one pages site per project. Every time you upload the `public` artifact for the pages site, it completely **overwrites and removes any existing content** on the Pages site for the project. For example, if you run the pages upload job in two different branches, only one can exist at a time on the Pages site, which is probably why you're getting the behavior you notice.

So, only the contents of one of your job's artifacts will ever be reflected in the gitlab pages site at any one time.

Also note that GitLab [expects the job is named `pages:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#gitlab-pages-requirements) for the Pages upload to work.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this happened. 
I want to have three subdirectories ( technically still one page )
Is it possible to do a pipeline that copies the current content of the public dir ( whole public with /next, /latest and /test ) inside, then override just single directory with the artifacts?

Comment: @ChristoPanayotov the only way would be if you have a single job to do the pages upload and that single job will need to create (or otherwise get) the full and complete contents (`/next`, `/latest` AND `/test`) ALL in the same job _every_ time it runs.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going this direction.